# How can I coerce long numbers in CSV files to strings so that Excel does not convert them to E notation?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

When using the standard CSV library, how can I coerce long numbers to strings so that Excel does not convert them to E notation?

For example, if I generate a CSV file with the value `1234567890` in it, when I open the file in Excel, the value is displayed as `1.235E+09`. I have to change the column width to see the original value.

My spec requires that the value be displayed in regular form (ie, `1234567890`) in the CSV file without requiring the user to change any settings in Excel or resize the column.

I've tried casting the value explicitly as a string without success:

```
CSV.generate_line([ value.to_s ])
```

Comment: AFAIK - That may be difficult - as formatting of 1.235E+09 is done by Excel, and there is nothing in CSV to prevent it.  You can generate an excel if you desire.  In excel, prefix a single quote (') helps to suppress that kind of formatting

Comment: The problem is Excel's default field width. CSV doesn't support setting individual field's format or type, and Excel's heuristics are determining the field is numeric, formatting it as such, and once displayed the field is too narrow. If you *must* use CSV, the only thing I think you can do is write a macro that loads the file for the user, then formats the fields as needed. You could output the data as XML, which lets you define all sorts of parameters for cells, but that's a totally different problem.

Comment: Your comments confirm what I suspected. In the end, I was able to get the requirements tweaked such that I could use the [Axlsx-Rails gem](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) to produce an Excel file. Nevertheless, thanks for the informed responses.

Comment: My solution does not qualify as a good answer, but its the only thing that has worked for me. I prepend the number with some characters, at which point it starts being treated as a normal string

Answer (score 1):

Generating an excel file itself sounds like a better option. However one *hacky* solution to avoid scientific notation for long numbers could be to have a helper such as:

```
def csv_text(val)
  "=TEXT(#{val},\"#\")"
end
```

... and use it accordingly where needed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The correct answer, I just tested today

Example working for me on Mac excel. Of course it add **non-breakable space** in front, so keep in mind it's not perfect and lead to **some troubles** in case of copy of the value for example!

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("./test.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  8.times do
     value = (rand * 0xffffffffffffffff).to_i #long number
     x = "\u00a0#{value}"
     ascii_str = x.unpack("U*").map{|c|c.chr}.join
     csv << [ascii_str, "other value", "other"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding a space doesn't help. Excel still defaults to the same width for a field, resulting in the problem of displaying the value as "########" or using exponential notation. Create a small CSV file and import it into Excel and experiment with that. Using `" #{value.to_s}"` is redundant; Instead `" #{value}"` will coerce the value to a string because of how interpolation works.

Comment: I can confirm that the first suggestion does not work. I did not have an opportunity to try the second but suspect similar disappointment for the reasons provided by @theTinMan [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506242/how-can-i-coerce-long-numbers-in-csv-files-to-strings-so-that-excel-does-not-con/33507383#comment54797452_33506242).

Comment: Then you should try the second. I just checked today and edited a bit the second solution, because it's working ;-)